# Cannot get standardPricebookEntry's id

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce-id, product, pricebook

I'm trying to write an Apex trigger and class, to update a list-price of a Product in a Pricebook, once a checkbox is clicked on the product object. Here is all of my code:

Class:

```
public class UpdatePriceBook {
    public static void UpdatePrice(Id productId, Id pricebookEntryId, Decimal newPrice){
         try {
            // Retrieve the product and pricebook entry
            Product2 product = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :productId];
            PricebookEntry pricebookEntry = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Pricebook2Id, UnitPrice FROM 
            PricebookEntry WHERE Id = :pricebookEntryId];

            // Update the price
            pricebookEntry.UnitPrice = newPrice;

            // Save the updated pricebook entry
            update pricebookEntry;

            System.debug('Price updated successfully for product: ' + product.Name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error updating price: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
    trigger UpdateProductPrice on Product2 (before insert) {
        if (Trigger.isBefore) {
            if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
                for (Product2 product : Trigger.new) {
                    if (product.ProductPriceUpdate__c) {
                        // Get the relevant PricebookEntry for this product
                        List<PricebookEntry> standardPricebookEntries = [
                        SELECT Id, UnitPrice
                        FROM PricebookEntry
                        WHERE Product2Id = :product.Id
                        AND Pricebook2.Name IN ('USA Pricebook', 'International PB')
                        AND Product2.Name = 'Cabinet'
                        AND Pricebook2.IsStandard = true
                        LIMIT 1
                         ];
    
                        if (!standardPricebookEntries.isEmpty()) {
                            PricebookEntry standardPricebookEntry = standardPricebookEntries[0].Id;                          
                            Decimal newPrice = 1500;
                            UpdatePriceBook.UpdatePrice(product.Id, pricebookEntryId, newPrice); // Replace with your desired price
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm stuck with is - that I need to get standardPricebookEntry's Id to pass it to the method in the class, but it seems like there is no option to get the id from the PricebookEntry standardPricebookEntry object.

I didn't realize when I started writing the code - that I was trying to modify the PricebookEntry object, but that isn't correct because the list price is a standardPricebookEntry field, not a PricebookEntry field, so that's how I have this line of code:

```
Id pricebookEntryId = pricebookEntries[0].Id;
```

But if I want to change it to be of type standardPricebookEntry like here:

```
PricebookEntry standardPricebookEntry = standardPricebookEntries[0].Id;
```

I get this error: "Illegal assignment from Id to PricebookEntry".

Thats because its assigning an id value to a PricebookEntry variable. But I do need the Id value - to pass to the class method - it's expecting to get an Id type parameter. What can I add to the code, or how can I modify it, to do what I described in the beginning of the question?

Comment: Can you just pass the Id into your method instead? It looks like you are setting `newPrice` twice unnecessarily. (Btw, are you planning to bulkify your trigger? You might want to do that first)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems in your code.

1. In salesforce you should always try to make your code suitable for bulk updates. Currently you are executing three queries for every iteration of your for loop and you are updating every pricebook entry separately.
2. Your query appears to contain too many checks in the where clause. Since you're checking the product Id, there's no point in checking the product name as well. The same goes for the pricebook name since only one record can be the standard pricebook.
3. Within your trigger you are checking for `Trigger.isUpdate` but currently the trigger wil only run before insert. And, since you're updating a different object you should use the after instead of before trigger.

I restructured your code a bit to account for these things

```
trigger UpdateProductPrice on Product2 (after insert, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
        Set<Id> updatedProductIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Product2 product : Trigger.new) {
            if (product.ProductPriceUpdate__c) {
                updatedProductIds.add(product.Id);
            }
        }
        if (!updatedProductIds.isEmpty()){
            List<PricebookEntry> pricebookEntriesToUpdate = new List<PricebookEntry>();
            for (PricebookEntry pbe : [
                    SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice
                    FROM PricebookEntry
                    WHERE Product2Id in :updatedProductIds
                    AND Pricebook2.IsStandard = true
            ]) {
                pbe.UnitPrice = 1500;
                pricebookEntriesToUpdate.add(pbe);
            }
            update pricebookEntriesToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

This works in my developer org.

Comment: Thank you! I did not mention it - but this is my first time writing a Trigger - I haven't used Apex ever before - I'm new to coding, so that can explain why the code is a little messy.
Is the class not included because there are no changes needed in it or you think its not needed?
 I do want to check in the trigger if the Pricebooks' name is "USA Pricebook" or "Internal PB",
and if so, I want to modify only a specific Products' price - that's why I put many conditions in the WHERE statement in the previous code.
So if it wasn't the correct way to do it - I'd like to know the correct way.

Comment: In the code I posted the class is not used anymore. The actual best practice is to make a triggerhandler class with functions like `beforeInsert`, `afterInsert`, `beforeUpdate`, `afterUpdate` and so on. Then you call these functions from your trigger. That way you can keep your code organized while having only one trigger per object, which is important because salesforce does not guarantee the order in which different apex triggers on the same object are executed.